# Is it normal to have heart palpitations in colder weather?

Tags: heart-rate, heart

I am moderately active, normal blood pressure, fairly average weight and build.  I've noticed that when I'm running in cold weather, about 5-10 minutes into my run I start to get what feel like heart palpitations, a somewhat uncomfortable but not painful fluttery feeling in my chest.  I don't get dizzy or anything, and am able to run normally, but I usually stop for a few minutes so I can make sure everything is ok.

I have had similar experiences when I used to work in a chilly building (65-68F) all day then walk out in the summer air (>95F).  For the first few minutes I'd get the feeling my heart wasn't beating fast enough, and it had the same fluttery feeling, but once I take a few breaths and give it a few minutes, things seem to normalize.

Why would this be happening?  Do I have bradycardia?  Could this be dangerous?

Comment: We can't diagnose you. The only thing we could do is list a bunch of possible reasons, but that wouldn't be an on-topic question.

Comment: Please speak to a physician about this.

Comment: There are known conditions where cold items in the throat (Such as swallowing ice) can cause a nerve response that disrupts/stops heart function. Please see your doctor, as death is a rather final consequence.

Comment: Not adding this as an answer since I'm not a physician, but your description fits that of premature ventricular contractions pretty well. While it's a normal thing to happen in adults, only a cardiologist can properly identify it and make sure there isn't anything bad causing it, so that's who you should ask to.

Comment: Feel your pulse when you feel the "flutter".  Does your pulse have a regular, or irregular rhythm?

Answer (score 2):

Palpitations can be a result of many things going on with your heart. Atrial Fibrillation, 1st 2nd or 3rd degree heart blocks, and a few others come to mind. The important thing to note is any time you heart starts doing something abnormal, even if you aren't sure if it is a normal response, CALL YOUR DOCTOR. Most exercise induced palpitations can be worked with if treated and monitored by a physician. If left un-diagnosed and untreated they can be fatal. When you call your doctor ask if having an exercise stress test with an EKG hooked up to you. (In all honesty they will suggest you do this anyway).

See your doctor sooner than later though. Good luck.

Comment: Don't forget that many palpitations are completely normal.

Comment: Anything irregular is abnormal. Palpitations, while abnormal, can be completely benign (harmless).

Comment: Depends on how you define irregular.  I was using "normal" in the sense of the number of people who have them, and their tendency to be benign.  I think you may have interpreted the term "abnormal" to mean a disturbance in the regular rhythm of the heart rate, as opposed to being uncommon among humans.

Comment: You stated that, "...palpitations are completely normal." You are correct though, I did interpret that as meaning that you thought palpitations were normal. If you would have said "common" in place of "normal" I would have definitely agreed with your statement. I just didn't want someone browsing this topic to get confused. Thanks for clarifying the miss communication.

Comment: I wanted readers to know that heart palpitations were common and benign and expected in healthy individuals.  This is usually the medical definition of normal.  An increase in heart rate during exercise is common and benign and expected.  I call this increase a normal increase.  Similarly, heart palpitations, while irregular, are definitely normal in life.

Comment: -1, for encouraging to ask for EKG stress test.  A proficient doctor will be able to determine if an EKG stress test is required or not, no need to request a test that is most likely not required.  Also -1 because no mention of ventricular ectopy.  -1, most exercise palpitations do not require any treatment from a physician, contrary to what your post leads people to believe.

Comment: -1 for flaming. -1 for not noticing that I mentioned the doctor would probably suggest they do it anyway. -1 because you fail to recognize that i said "many other things." -1 for drawing asinine inferences because you are butt-hurt. -1 because you fail to recognize that you are still trying to say the OP shouldn't worry about it because "most exercise palpitations do not require any treatment." -1 for thinking that an increase in heart rate and palpitations are the same thing.

Comment: I drew an analogy between increased heart rate and palpitations, not an equivalence relation, hence the word "similarly".

Comment: The OP shouldn't worry about palpitations, but that doesn't mean he shouldn't get it checked with a doctor.  Palpitations are naturally quite distressing and most physicians think patients shouldn't stop worrying about them as it adds to this distress.  I never said the patient shouldn't see a doctor.  He should, but your post makes palpitations seem very scary, and add to patient distress.

Comment: If by "scary" you mean that I said that anytime the person thinks something is abnormal that they should call their doctor. Including that most palpitations are treatable and benign. What IS scary is that you are downplaying something that has the potential to be fatal if left untreated. Since SE won't let me move this to chat for whatever reason, lets just agree that we have both devolved into posting non-beneficial posts and let this topic Close as suggested by other community members.

Comment: Most palpitations are not treatable.  Most palpitations are labelled as benign, and the patient is sent away with nothing.  You did not mention this in your post, hence the -1. (along with other reasons mentioned above)